# Flash CC - Actionscript 3 scaling issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

Hello and thanks for taking the time.

In my app i have a movieClip called "gameHandler" which adds the levels of the game. So this is the process the game goes through:

step1: figure out the device width and height

step2: set the width and height of "gameHandler" accordingly

step3: addChild(level1), level1.width and height is set to device width/height

and here the problem comes in. level 1 width and height are correct when i trace(.widht/.height) but on screen they are much smaller than they should be. Both the parent clip(gameHandler) and the child clip(level1) are the same width and height, and yet, they are not. Im guessing this has something to do with scaling but ive tried NO_SCALE and it didnt help. Any assistance is deeply appreciated.

If it wasn't clear; Im coding in actionscript 3 (Air for ios) and im using flash professional cc 2014

Answer (score 0):

You should skip your step 2, as this adds scaling to `gameHandler` which is then applied to all nested objects. Instead, properly scale `level1` after adding, so that it will span the whole of the device's available area.

Comment: Thanks for replying! Hmm, but how do i scale gameHandler then? It's like a start menu so the visuals needs to fit the screensize

Comment: If so, you need to add `level1` NOT to `gameHandler` but to its parent, so that `gameHandler` will only contain menu.